# Custom Panel Providing Both Datatemplate And non-Datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, custom-controls, itemscontrol

I would like to create a panel that I will be able to use it like below examples.

**example 1:**

```
<custom:CustomPanel ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}">
    <custom:CustomPanel.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </custom:CustomPanel.ItemTemplate>
</custom:CustomPanel>
```

**example 2:**

```
<custom:CustomPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="text1" />
    <TextBlock Text="text2" />
    <TextBlock Text="text3" />
</custom:CustomPanel>
```

I implemented first one and I can use it now properly. I provided it by inheriting regarding class from *ItemsControl* like below.

```
class CustomPanel : ItemsControl{
    ...
}
```

How can I provide second one example work?

Comment: The second example also works out of the box when you derive from ItemsControl.

Answer (score -1):

For second one you need to inherit from ContentControl.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. ContentControl can have only one direct child.